# Argo Events Kafka triggers cannot parse message headers to enable distributed tracing

Tags: apache-kafka, datadog, argo-workflows, distributed-tracing, argo-events

**TL;DR** - Argo Events Kafka eventsource triggers do not currently parse headers of consumed Kafka message, which is needed to enable distributed tracing. I submitted a feature request ([here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/issues/2442)) - if you face the same problem please upvote, and curious if anyone figured out a workaround.

====================================

### **Context**

Common pattern of Argo Workflows we deploy are Kafka event-driven, asynchronous distributed workloads, e.g.:

- Service "A" Kafka producer that emits message to topic
- Argo Events eventsource Kafka trigger listening to that topic
- Argo Workflow gets triggered, and post-processing...
- ... service "B" Kafka producer at end of workflow emits that work is done.

To monitor the entire system for user-centric metrics "how long did it take & where are the bottle necks", I'm looking to instrument distributed tracing from service "A" to service "B". We use Datadog as aggregator, with `dd-trace`.

Pattern I've seen is manual propagation of trace ctx via Kafka headers - by injecting headers to Kafka messages before emitting (similar to HTTP headers, with parent trace metadata), and receiving Consumer once done processing the message will then add child_span to that parent_span received from upstream.

ex) of above: https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/distributed-tracing-with-kafka

---

### **Issue**

Argo-Events Kafka event source trigger does not parse any headers, only passing the body json for downstream Workflow to use at `eventData.Body`.
[[source code]](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/eventsources/sources/kafka/start.go#L391)

**Simplified views of my Argo Eventsource -> Trigger -> Workflow:**

```
# eventsource/my-kafka-eventsource.yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: EventSource
spec:
  kafka:
    my-kafka-eventsource:
      topic: <my-topic>
      version: "2.5.0"
```

```
# sensors/trigger-my-workflow.yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
spec:
  dependencies:
    - name: my-kafka-eventsource-dep
      eventSourceName: my-kafka-eventsource
      eventName: my-kafka-eventsource
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: start-my-workflow
        k8s:
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              spec:
                entrypoint: my-sick-workflow
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                    - name: proto_message
                      value: needs to be overriden
                    # I would like to be able to add this
                    - name: msg_headers
                      value: needs to be overriden
                templates:
                  - name: my-sick-workflow
                    dag:
                      tasks:
                        - name: my-sick-workflow
                          templateRef:
                            name: my-sick-workflow
                            template: my-sick-workflow
          parameters:
            # content/body of consumed message
            - src: 
                dependencyName: my-kafka-eventsource-dep
                dataKey: body  
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
            # I would like to do this - get msg.headers() if exists.
            - src: 
                dependencyName: my-kafka-eventsource-dep
                dataKey: headers
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.1.value
```

```
# templates/my-sick-workflow.yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
spec:
  templates:
    - name: my-sick-workflow
      container:
        image: <image>
        command: [ "python", "/main.py" ] 
        # I want to add the 2nd arg - msg_headers - here
        args: [ "{{workflow.parameters.proto_message}}", "{{workflow.parameters.msg_headers}}" ]

# so that in my Workflow Dag step source code, 
# I can access headers of Kafka msg from upstream by.... 
# body=sys.argv[1], headers=sys.argv[2]
```

**Confluent-Kafka API docs** on accessing message headers: [[doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#:%7E:text=None%20or%20KafkaError-,headers(),-Retrieve%20the%20headers)]

---

### **Q's**

1. Has anyone found a workaround on passing tracing context from upstream to downstream service that travels between Kafka Producer<>Argo Events?
2. I considered changing my Argo-Workflows sensor trigger to HTTP trigger accepting payloads, by a new Kafka consumer listening for the message that is currently triggering my Argo Workflow --> then forward HTTP payload with parent trace metadata in headers.

   - it's anti-pattern to rest of my workflows, so I would like to avoid if there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the only real workaround without forking some part of Argo Events, or implementing your own Source/Sensor yourself would be to use a Kafka Consumer (or Kafka Connect), and call a WebHook EventSource (or another, which can extract the information you need).

Comment: thanks - yea that is the approach I went with. It came with refactoring cost but does give us flexibility in long-run that Argo Events default Kafka eventsource seemed to lack